# How to check if the caller method in a class is instance of an interface?

Tags: java

I have an interface as below

```
public interface AccessController {

}
```

I have a class as below

```
public class LocalDriver {
   WebDriver driver;

   public static WebDriver driver() {
       if ("need to know?" instanceof AccessController)
           return driver;
       else
           return null;
   }
}
```

Then I have a caller class

```
public class CallerClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDriver.driver();
    }

}
```

Now how do I check if the `CallerClass` is an`instanceOf` `AccessController` `interface` in the `driver()` method which is in a different class?

Comment: What's the point? Don't you know if the class you're in implements `AccessController`? What do you mean by "caller method"?

Comment: Modified my question

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the caller into your `static` method and interrogate it. Something like:

```
public static WebDriver driver(Object caller) {
   if (caller instanceof AccessController)
    return driver;
   else 
    return null;
 }
```

You would use this in the following manner:

```
// In the caller
LocalDriver.driver(this);
```

If you also need to support this concept from a static context, you could try:

```
public static WebDriver driver(Class<?> callerClass) {
   if (caller.isAssignableFrom(AccessController.class))
    return driver;
   else 
    return null;
 }
```

This can be called from both contexts:

```
LocalDriver.driver(this.getClass());  // instance context
LocalDriver.driver(CallerClass.class);  // static context
```

Comment: The caller is a static method. Better to accept a `Class<?>` parameter.